# API Connect On Premise OVA Properties

Tags: apiconnect

I noticed while deploying API Connect that the OVA had a variety of useful properties that I could set to get my on premise deployment up and running much more rapidly and securely. I couldn't find any documentation on them though. Can someone explain what all of these properties do?

I've bolded the ones I really care about, but bonus points if you explain them all and show how to craft an `ovftool` command to set those properties.

- hostname
- domain
- Ip Address
- Netmask
- Gateway
- Primary DNS
- Secondary DNS
- NTP
- Domain Search
- **Cloud IP address**
- Username
- Password
- **Email**

Answer (score 0):

These properties are referenced in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.install.doc/overview_installing_mgmtvm_apimgmt.html

When configuring multiple (a cluster of) management nodes into a management service, use the Cloud IP address to tell the 2nd..nth nodes where to find the 1st (leave blank for the 1st node).

Email is the email address of the Cloud Manager "admin" user.